# Ant ignores attempt to override the LANG environment variable

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables, locale

We need to test a java build with the languages set to different values. I can manually (i.e. via `export LANG=en_DK.UTF-8` and `export LANG=en_DK`) test that the unit tests run with the ant build script behaves differently, but I need to set the environment variable from ant. I have tried setting it using these methods (with the shell `$LANG` set to `en_DK.UTF-8`):

1. using `-D` on the command line: `ant -DLANG=en_DK`
2. using a `build.properties` file with the line `LANG=en_DK` in it
3. using the following statements in the build.xml file (sorry for the formatting, I can't get SO to display it otherwise):

:

```
<property environment="ANTENV"/>
<property name="ANTENV.LANG" value="en_DK"/>
```

Using any of the three possibilities, and when run with `-debug`, ant reports that:

```
Override ignored for property "LANG"
```

What can I do to set the `LANG` environment variable from within ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANT Properties are immutable](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html),

```
<property name="ANTENV.LANG" value="en_DK"/>
```

may be be interpreted by ant as an attempt to override the `LANG` value already present when storing all the environment variables in `ANTENV` (with `<property environment="ANTENV"/>`).

So you need to store to store that value in a separate property.

```
<property name="MY.LANG" value="${env.LANG}" />
```

Comment: But I don't really need to store the value; I need to set it so that the JVM, when executing the tests, can use either the value en_DK or en_DK.UTF-8 as LANG. I acknowledge that the ant properties are immutable, I would just like to meddle with the environment variables from within ant...

Comment: @Steen: "I would just like to meddle with the environment variables from within ant": that is what   `<property name="MY.LANG" value="${env.LANG}" />` allows you to do: once seet, you can reuse it within other tasks. What you cannot do is to change something set outside of the Ant session (like an environment value)

Comment: OK, that qualifies as an answer to my question. Not the one I really wanted to hear, but that's my problem. I've experimented with wrapping the call to the build-file in a shell-script that sets the LANG environment before calling ant. I works fine, but feels like a hack ;)

Comment: @Steen: Also, you could try to set value to `ANTENV.LANG` before defining environment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "test a java build" is done by a call to `<java>`, you could use the fork-flag and pass properties to the newly created process. Here's an example from the [Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

```
  <java classname="test.Main"
        fork="yes" >
    <sysproperty key="DEBUG" value="true"/>
    <arg value="-h"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Xrunhprof:cpu=samples,file=log.txt,depth=3"/>
  </java>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As noted on VonC's answer I reach my purpose through a shell script wrapper. Your solution amounts to the same effect, but it also (like my shell script wrapper solution) feels hacky. Thanks for you answer, though.